# ETL mapping to load employee whose first name has space in it in informatica Power Center

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Consider employees table as source. Create an ETL mapping to load employee whose first name has space in it.
**E.g** First name like (Jose Manuel, John Paul)

Comment: You can use `instr(data_col,' ' ) >0` condition in a filter. Or is there any other complexity that isnt mentioned here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSTR function,

```
INSTR(first_name, ' ') != 0
```

Comment: tried but didn't worked. :)